# Как вызвать функцию при определенном событии 1С?

Tags: 1с

Есть сайт, нужно при входе как-то получить данные пользователей и их ролей из базы 1С, а как это сделать не понятно.

Изначально хотел обращаться напрямую к базе PostgreSQL, но там зашифрованы данные ролей.

Ещё есть идея каким-то образом следить за изменениями ролей и при их изменении генерировать отчет со всеми пользователями и их правами, который будет сохраняться в файл. Тогда при входе на сайт можно будет читать этот файлик и выводить результат. Но как именно сделать генерацию отчета при изменении (добавлении новой или удалении старой) какой-либо роли у пользователя?

Comment: Можете интегрироваться с 1С посредством Web-, HTTP-сервиса.

Answer (score 3):

Для этого конфигурация 1С должна предоставлять этот функционал ! Внутри конфигурации - создайте http сервис, который отвечая на get запрос получает данные из базы и отдает наружу.